# How can I access aspnet Dependency Injection service inside a static class?

Tags: asp.net-core

In my aspnet core application, I have a static class that acts as a façade and provide some general-purpose services to the rest of the application.

The static class needs to use aspnet core dependency injection to get instances from the DI repository.

How can I use aspnet DI inside a static class? All I need is to get a reference to the ServiceCollection.

Comment: Create a Singleton Instance Wrapper so that you can attach the static facade with a service provider.  And then you can inject this Wrapper service everywhere.

Comment: @itminus, yes, that is a workaround. But other DI libraries (such as Unity) have this feature. For my own enducation, I like to know where is the API that let me access the service collection.